# Windows Live Authentication in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-live-id

So looking around the web, I see tons of tutorials for integrating Live authentication into projects, but have found almost nothing useful on integrating into an MVC project. I'm pretty new to MVC, and have some limited experience with Web Forms.

The site I'm trying to make must allow authenticated Live users to submit and vote on various items, so I need to figure out the best way to keep track of users' submissions as well as votes so that they can vote only one time on a submissions, and cannot vote on their own submissions.

I'm wondering if anyone can simply point me in the right direction here.  I see that similar questions have been asked, but the answers to them didn't seem to lead me to an answer.

Comment: I suggest going through this doc/tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx  Come back here with specific questions as to what you don't understand or need help with

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the OAuth2 authentication, Live supports it for some time. You can use any existing approach to OAuth2, dotnetopenauth is fine.

MVC does not change anything. You just have your forms authentication login controller which initiates the redirect to the authentication provider and consumes the return response.

Some links to get you started:

General info on OAuth2 for various providers:
http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/oauth-providers

OAuth2 on Live:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx

Integration of OAuth in an MVC application:
http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/